# Compass Bootstrap Sass on Mac

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass

I am having problems compiling my project. I installed everything non-Rails using gems. I am getting these errors:

```
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:60:in `register_compass_extension': uninitialized constant Compass::Frameworks (NameError)
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:5:in `load!'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.1/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:74:in `'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass.rb:9:in `'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/bin/compass:20:in `block in '
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/bin/compass:19:in `'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/compass:23:in `load'
from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/compass:23:in `'
```

I uninstall sass and bootstrap (and re-installed) and now am getting these errors:

```
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass.rb: line 1: module: command not found
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass.rb: line 2: end: command not found
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass.rb: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `dependencies'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.7/lib/compass.rb: line 4: `%w(dependencies util browser_support sass_extensions version errors quick_cache logger).each do |lib|'
```